# Need help in for loop in kshell scripting for linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, ksh

Can someone says how the below works?

```
server.ksh file contains the below.
n=$1   ### what does this do ? 
ssh $n date;
```

test is a file that contains a list of 50 servers.
Now I run the below.

```
for a in `cat test`; do ksh server.ksh $a >> date$a & done
```

Just having a random look at the above u can say it just print the date of all the servers and save the o/p.**But the thing is it hits all the servers at the exact same time!!**(i.e not like a traditional for loop one after another). Can someone please break this up and explain ?

Comment: None of this is specific to `ksh`, and you should broaden the scope of the question by omitting the `ksh` tag and removing `kshell` from the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# assign variable 'n' the value of the first input parameter to
# the server.ksh invocation; a server name in this case
n=$1

# make a ssh call to the server whose name is stored in
# variable 'n', on the remote host run the 'date' command
ssh $n date;
```

Your while loop is kicking off the `server.ksh` calls in the background (**&**); this allows the loop to continue to the next iteration while the server.ksh call is still being processed; net result is you end up with multiple `ssh` calls in flight at the same time.

It only looks like everything is done at the same exact time because the default output of the `date` command is only precise to the nearest second.  If you increase the precision of the `date` output you'll likely see that the `ssh` calls aren't done at 'exactly' the same time, eg:

```
# output format: HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn (nano-seconds)
ssh $n "date +'%H:%M:%S.%N'";
```

Obviously (?) there could also be discrepancies in the `date` outputs if the various servers' system clocks are off by even a fraction of a fraction of a second.

Comment: Can you please tell me what cause it to go to bg?

Comment: the ampersand character - `&` - says to run the `server.ksh` call in the background

Comment: Am not sure.. Isn't that a logical and &  in this case print and exiting while done?

Comment: I'm sure ... a `logical AND` is double ampersands - `&&`; besides, if you were to rewrite that `while` loop as a multi-line construct you'd find the `server.ksh` invocation is the last command in the loop (ie, there's nothing to `logically AND` it with)

Comment: Thanks mate.. An New to scripting..  And n=$1 in this case is?

Comment: The server name is passed as a parameter here. .. But I still don't get the use of n=$1